# Tagging Photos via Facebook GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, tags, facebook-graph-api, photos

Facebook recently added photo-tagging capabilities to its Graph API:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/

I am using FbConnect on iPhone to upload a picture and tag my page inside it.
So, my first call is:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   self.imageToPost, @"picture",
                                   @"My caption!", @"name", @"tags",
                                   nil];

    [self.theFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];
```

This correctly returns:
{
    id = 2092859844825;
}

Then I make another call:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID,@"to", 
                                   @"160",@"x", 
                                   @"240",@"y", 
                                   nil];

    [self.theFacebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tags",photoId]
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];
```

Then I get:
{contents = "OAuthException"}
{contents = "**(#121) Invalid photo id**"}

But what ID does it expect from me?
Submitting the same request in GET method, it doesn't give the error, so I think the id is correct. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What permissions do you have set? Check you have the `user_photos` permission